# XAML and ViewModel Binding inside ControlTemplate

Tags: c++, windows, xaml, winrt-xaml, uwp-xaml

I want to **utilize the ViewModel function within the .xaml.cpp and .xaml** file. I have created the ViewModel's getter and setter functions and attempted to bind it within the controlTemplate, where it is locally defined.

Unfortunately, I am encountering an issue where the **ViewModel is returning as null** when I attempt to use it and hence the visibility/SizeChanged of the grid in ShoppingItem.xaml is not set properly. The debug pointer is not reaching to the ShoppingItem::ViewModel::set(ViewModels::ShoppingItemVM ^ value) function and the get function is always returning null viewModel.

I have tried multiple combination while binding the viewModel in UserControl of ShoppingToApps.xaml  but still the ViewModel::set never gets called.

```
<local:ShoppingItem ViewModel="{Binding}"/\>
<local:ShoppingItem ViewModel="{Binding viewModels:ShoppingItemVM}"/\>
<local:ShoppingItem DataContext="{Binding}"/\>
<local:ShoppingItem ViewModel="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=DataContext}"/\>
<local:ShoppingItem ViewModel="{TemplateBinding}"/\>
```

**ShoppingToApps.xaml**

```
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="ClipboardItemTemplate" x:DataType="viewModels:ClipboardItemVM">
            <local:CopyToClipboardItem ViewModel="{x:Bind}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="InstalledAppTemplate" x:DataType="viewModels:ShoppingItemVM" >
            <tc:TileCustomControl
                x:Name="TileControl"
                IsTabStop="False"
                ViewModel="{x:Bind TileControlViewModel, Mode=OneWay}"
                AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Control"
                AutomationProperties.AutomationId="{x:Bind Label}"
                AutomationProperties.Name="{x:Bind TileControlViewModel.Label, Mode=OneWay}">
                <tc:TileCustomControl.Template>
                    <ControlTemplate>
                        <local:ShoppingItem ViewModel="{Binding}"/>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </tc:TileCustomControl.Template>
            </tc:TileCustomControl>
        </DataTemplate>
        <local:TargetAppTemplateSelector
            x:Key="TargetAppTemplateSelector"
            ClipboardItem="{StaticResource ClipboardItemTemplate}"
            InstalledApp="{StaticResource InstalledAppTemplate}"/>
    </UserControl.Resources>
```

**ShoppingItem.xaml**

```
<UserControl x:Class="ShoppingPickerUI.ShoppingItem"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             xmlns:util="using:ShoppingdUtilities"
             xmlns:local="using:ShoppingPickerUI"
             d:DesignHeight="300"
             d:DesignWidth="400" 
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             ToolTipService.ToolTip="{x:Bind local:ToolTipHelper.ResolveToolTip(LabelText.Text, LabelText.IsTextTrimmed), Mode=OneWay}">
    <Grid>
        x:Name="DefaultAppGrid"
        SizeChanged="AddPromotedRow"
        Style="{StaticResource ShoppingItemRootGridStyleSV}"
        Visibility="{Binding ViewModel.IsDefaultLabelVisible}">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Rectangle 
            Grid.Row="0"
            Style="{StaticResource ShoppingItemPlateStyleSV}" >
            <Rectangle.Fill>
                <SolidColorBrush Color="{Binding PlateColor}"/>
            </Rectangle.Fill>
        </Rectangle>
        <Border 
            Grid.Row="0"
            BorderThickness="2"
            Style="{StaticResource ShoppingItemPlateStyleSV}" />
        <Image
            Grid.Row="0"
            Source="{Binding Icon}"
            Style="{StaticResource ShoppingItemIconStyleSV}" 
            AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw"/>
        <local:TwoLinesTextBlock 
            x:Name="LabelText" 
            Grid.Row="1" 
            Text="{Binding Label}"/>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

**ShoppingItem.xaml.cpp**

```
#include "pch.h"
#include "ShoppingItem.xaml.h"
#include <ShoppingItemVM.h>

using namespace ShoppingPickerUI;
using namespace ShoppingdUtilities;

ShoppingItem::ShoppingItem()
{
 InitializeComponent(ref new ::Windows::Foundation::Uri(GetFullFileResourcePath(L"ShoppingPickerUI/ShoppingItem.xaml")));
}

void ShoppingItem::AddPromotedRow()
{
    if (ViewModel != nullptr)
    {
        //ViewModel is coming as null
        //Call some ViewModel.func_defined_in_VM();
    }
}


ViewModels::ShoppingItemVM ^ ShoppingItem::ViewModel::get()
{
    return m_viewModel;
}

void ShoppingItem::ViewModel::set(ViewModels::ShoppingItemVM ^ value)
{
    if (m_viewModel != value)
    {
        m_viewModel = value;
        PropertyChanged(this, ref new Windows::UI::Xaml::Data::PropertyChangedEventArgs(L"ViewModel"));
    }
}
```

Comment: Can't reproduce the issue with your code.  I'd suggest you simplify your code instead of using nested control first. The datacontext should be the problem. It better to check the datacontext for `TileCustomControl` and `ShoppingItem`  by handling the datacontext change event.